# constraintWidth_percent does not calculate correctly

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

This layout will display a View with a color and another with another color.

When layout_constraintWidth_percent = 1 the views are the same width. When I set it between 0.92 <> 1 the foreground view becomes bigger then the background.

Can anyone solve this? I need the foreground to be x percentage of the background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    >

  <View
      android:id="@+id/background"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      />

  <View
      android:id="@+id/foreground"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:background="@color/colorAccent"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.94"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/background"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/background"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background"
      />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the start and end margins of the background. If you want left and right margins, put them on the parent ConstraintLayout instead. As it is now you have margins on background but not on foreground.

Also set the background width to 0dp (the same as foreground). This way the background will be the full width of the parent ConstraintLayout (which can itself apply the margins you want) and the foreground will be the specified percentage of the background. Also set the horizontal bias of the foreground to 0.5 if you want it to be centered.

Like this [image: (here's what this layout looks like)]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    >

  <View
      android:id="@+id/background"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      />

  <View
      android:id="@+id/foreground"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:background="@color/colorAccent"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.94"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background"
      />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you this is the neatest solution. It seems it ignores the margins in its calculations of it's width (although start is set). It is a progress bar which is why it's bias is set to 0

Answer (score 0):

The `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` attribute is calculated according to the parent `ConstraintLayout's` dimension and not the horizontal constraints of the `View`. So you need to wrap the foreground in another `ConstraintLayout` like this (which is a bit ugly because of the nested layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/foreground"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.94"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Keep in mind that using `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` and margins on a `View` at the same time can potentially lead to some problems because the margins aren't taken into account for the width percentage.

You can also consider removing the margins from the background and possibly adding them to root `ConstraintLayout` as padding and I think this would help avoid having a nested layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/foreground"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.94"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated from the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout), the percentage is relative to the parent:

> When a dimension is set to **MATCH_CONSTRAINT**, the default behavior is
>   to have the resulting size take all the available space. Several
>   additional modifiers are available:
>
> - **layout_constraintWidth_min** and **layout_constraintHeight_min** : will set
>     the minimum size for this dimension
> - **layout_constraintWidth_max** and
>     **layout_constraintHeight_max** : will set the maximum size for this
>     dimension
> - **layout_constraintWidth_percent** and
>     **layout_constraintHeight_percent** : will set the size of this dimension
>     as a percentage of the parent